# How do I send Heart Rate data from Samsung Galaxy Watch to a nodejs server (using Tizen)?

Tags: node.js, xml, tizen, samsung-galaxy, heartrate

I have some issues concerning a project of mine. Specifically, the project consists of creating an app in **Tizen** that records Heart Rate (HR) data and sends them from a Samsung Galaxy Watch (where the app is installed) to a server that I have created with **nodejs**.
I have problems with the `main.js` file of the app: in order to send data to the server I have mentioned above, I use `XmlHttpRequest()` to create a POST request. Unfortunately, data are not sent to the server even though no errors come out while installing the app from Tizen in the smartwatch.
Has anyone developed a similar project? Does anyone know how to create the connection between server and smartwatch to send HR data?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Vittoria.

Comment: Hello, would you let us know your project type: Native / Web / .NET apps? I think... sending data to server directly is a difficult approach than using Mobile device (companion device). could you consider this approach? Wearable => Companion Device => Server

Comment: it is a Web app project

Comment: It's a web app installed on a watch?  If it is an app installed on a Samsung device try runing `adb logcat` to catch any errors that occur and add some logging info so you see it in logcat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.